# Step form function button and submit one

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have two forms on the same page.

Each form has two or three function buttons.

The submit button is not working.

Below is the step button.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
   <button class="btn btn-choco open4" type="button"> Command - Stage 2 >></button>
   <button class="btn btn-choco open5" type="button" style="display:none;"> Command - Stage 3 >></button>
   <button class="btn btn-choco open6" type="button" style="display:none;"> Command - stage 4 >></button>
   <button class="btn btn-choco" type="submit" name="submit" id="checkout-button" style="display:none;"> Command>></button>
</div>
```

My form is doted of an action page which is the page I want to reach and method post.

When the last step is validate, the 'checkout button' appears by function too.

Where is my error?

It's working when I add `novalidate` to the form. Can someone explain about `novalidate?

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Comment: Your bug is you have no JavaScript.

Comment: What does _"The submit one is not working"_ mean? Is the form not submitted (developer tools -> network tab)? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I have script to make appear submit button at the end of my process.

Comment: the submit is not working means  the form action is not reach. no errors in console